# Python - Socket - Networking - Very Simple

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking

Unfortunately I am unable to find an answer for this even after an hour of searching.

I borrowed this from online tutorials - Youtube - Draps

```
import socket, threading, time, wx

tLock = threading.Lock()
shutdown = False

def receiving(name, sock):

    while not shutdown:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            #while True:
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            print str(data) + "hehehe"
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 0
server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.setblocking(0)

rT = threading.Thread(target = receiving, args = ("RecvThread", s))
rT.start()

alias = raw_input("Name: ")
message = raw_input(alias + "-->")


while message != 'q':
    if message != '':
        s.sendto(alias + ":" + message, server)
    tLock.acquire()
    message = raw_input(alias + "-->")
    tLock.release()
    time.sleep(0.2)


shutdown = True
rT.join()
s.close()
```

I have two questions:

1. In the code, `host = '127.0.0.1'`. However if I use `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`, I get a socket error. Could anyone tell me why is this so? When I deploy a similar code to an external computer, it should not have this problem of creating a socket.
2. I started a thread that runs continuously. Why is the shutdown value (which is declared after the thread has started) able to stop the rT thread and break the while loop? I am unable to understand the physics and surprised it is working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on the first question but for the second one `shutdown` is a global variable.  Any threads spawned from the main thread have the ability to see the `shutdown`

Can you post the socket error you are getting?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kundemj/Desktop/Web Scraping/client.py", line 35, in <module>
    s.sendto(alias + ":" + message, server)
socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: Would it also work, if both my variable and thread are defined in a class of main thread?

Comment: @jesh I'm not sure I understand your question?  what do you mean "in a class of main thread"

Comment: also, that error you are getting has nothing to do with the variable `host`.  You are trying to send data to `server` and it doesn't like that address.  It could be for any number of reasons.  Try not using the loopback?  Are you actually running a server on port 5000?

Comment: Well it has to do with the "host" as it is working when host = '127.0.0.1' and my server is also on '127.0.0.1' port 5000. So if deploy my client code to another computer, what should be an universal value for the "host" variable?

Comment: My question is, I create a class for my GUI using wxpython. In that class, I give details of buttons etc. When I press a button, it starts a thread. The thread has a while loop as similar to the present question. If I want to stop the thread using an other button, where should I properly give my shutdown  =True to stop the process and finally join the thread? Buttons create events - how would the thread know the variable modified in a different event.

Comment: interesting, what is the ip address you get back from `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`?

Comment: I get a private IP address - 10.0.70.XX

Comment: It's possible that because you are using a routable IP address (as opposed to the loopback) you cannot send data TO the loopback (which is what the server is on).  I'm not an expert in this area though and I don't have the ability to check.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and input. Any comments on my question regarding a thread in the class?

Comment: There are a multitude of ways you can do this.  One of the easiest is to pass your thread an object of a singleton class with an attribute it checks (aka shutdown).  Then update the singleton from wherever you want and the thread will check the attribute and shutdown.

If I helped at all I would appreciate an "up" arrow on my answer.  Thanks.